# matriz de objetos y moverme objeto por matriz (JAVA)

Tags: java, array, poo

como están?, tratare de ser lo mas especifico posible, y espero que esta sea la manera mas adecuada de hacer preguntas(porque son 2), el caso necesito crear una matriz donde pueda guardar instancias de objetos, además de poder acceder a dicha matriz desde cualquier otra clase, esto ultimo porque quiero agregarle una interfaz donde se mostraría el objeto en una especie de tablero.

probé creando una matriz de la clase, pero no logro acceder a esta desde otra clase, dejo parte del código del main para que se pueda entender.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
// VARIABLES, INTANCIAS y CONFIGURACIONES DEL SISTEMA GENERAL

//creo instancia de la clase config, que es donde tengo todas las variables, estas variables las conectare para poder modificarlas antes de hacer andar el programa (refieriendo a la interfaz grafica)
    configuracion config = new configuracion();
     animales matriz[][] = new animales[config.getFila()][config.getColumna()];
        
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        

    
//ESPECIES
    //HALCON
                                    
        for(int a = 0;a<config.getCantidad_Halcon();){
            if(a < config.getCantidad_Halcon()){
                int i = r.nextInt(matriz.length);
                int j = r.nextInt(matriz[0].length);
                if(matriz[i][j]==null){
                    matriz[i][j] = new animales("Halcon"+a,config.getMin_reproducion_Halcon(),config.getMax_reproducion_Halcon(),
                            config.getMin_Vida_Halcon(),config.getMax_Vida_Halcon(),config.getMin_alimentacion_Halcon(),config.getMax_alimentacion_Halcon(),i);
                    a++;
                }                                  
            }                                            
        }
```

como explique antes logro crear el array de dos dimensiones, logro ingresar valores de objetos, pero no logro hacer una mención de este en otra clase, y por lo que entiendo necesito poder mencionar este array para poder mostrarlo gráficamente en jpanel.

ese es mi principal problema, y el segundo que espero sea mas simple es que suponiendo que x objeto esta en un array[10][10] y la posición de x es 4,2 que se mueva para cualquier lado a un espacio, por ejemplo al lado 5,2 , intente haciendo que verifique los especias con una cantidad increíble de if y else if, pero me dice que excedo el tamaño del array dejo el código por si sirve también.

```
//el tamaño de la matriz es de 10x10
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {               
            if(matriz[i][j] != null){                   
                if(matriz[i][j].getId() == 0 && matriz[i][j].getNombre().equals("Planta")){                  
                    System.out.println(i+"soy i antes");
                    System.out.println(j+"soy j antes");
                    if(matriz[i+1][j] == null ){
                        matriz[i+1][j] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i+1][j].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i-1][j] == null){                       
                        matriz[i-1][j] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i-1][j].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i][j+1] == null){
                        matriz[i][j+1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i][j+1].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i][j-1] == null){
                        matriz[i][j-1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i][j-1].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i+1][j+1] == null){
                        matriz[i+1][j+1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i+1][j+1].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i-1][j-1] == null){
                        matriz[i-1][j-1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i-1][j-1].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i+1][j-1] == null){
                        matriz[i+1][j-1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i+1][j-1].getId());
                        
                    }else if(matriz[i-1][j+1] == null){
                        matriz[i-1][j+1] = matriz[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matriz[i-1][j+1].getId());
                    }
                
                } 
            }
```

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda y consejos para mejorar en java y en esta plataforma.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Muy buena pregunta, bien formulada... Tu matriz de animales debe estar al nivel de la clase, no dentro del metodo... y no verifiques si a matriz es null.. mejor verifica que x o j no se pasaron de tu longitud o no son menor que cero...

Comment: @gbianchi FUNCIONOOO muchas graciassss, llevaba desde ayer estresado con eso, muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo.

Comment: Si funciono, recuerda responderte a vos mismo entonces... con una respuesta bien formulada tambien.. explicando el problema y la solucion...

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo como dijo gbianchi, el problema 1 se arreglaba creando la matriz dentro de la misma clase, en donde deseaba ocuparla.

```
animales matriz[][] = new animales[config.getFila()][config.getColumna()];
// se crea dentro de la misma clase animales, lo que permite acceder a la 
  //matriz si creo una instancia de esta
```

y a la segunda pregunta era comparando las longitudes con el valor por el cual me quería mover.

```
 int matriz[][] = new int[10][10]
y si quiero agregar un dato en matriz[10+1][10] ocupo un if que verifica la longitud
if(matriz.lenght //filas >= matriz.lenght+1){hacer algo}
```

me funciono de esa manera, gracias de nuevo por la ayuda gbianchi <3333